# Migration from Embedded ElasticSearch to spring-data-elasticsearch 4.0.6.RELEASE

Tags: java, spring-data, spring-data-elasticsearch

I am working on a small project that needs to be migrated to a more current Spring version.

I am having troubles fixing this query:

```
SearchResponse response = new SearchRequestBuilder(node.client())
    .setIndices(INDEX)
    .setTypes(TYPE_MYCLASS)
    .setFrom(page * PAGE_SIZE)
    .setSize(PAGE_SIZE)
    .setQuery(
        new FilteredQueryBuilder(
            new MatchAllQueryBuilder()
            , new TermFilterBuilder("mostRecent", true)
        )
    )
    .get();

SearchHit[] hits = response.getHits().getHits();
```

I have already migrated the DTO-Class (TYPE_MYCLASS) to Spring-Data Document annotation

```
@Mapping(
    mappingPath = "es/mappings/myclass.json")
@Document(
    indexName = ElasticsearchService.INDEX
    , type = ElasticsearchService.TYPE_MYCLASS)
public class MyClass {
    public Boolean mostRecent;
    // other Fields
}
```

Hoping that an expert could help me.

Comment: What is the problem? What exactly do not work?

Comment: The API has changed, and I am having troubles finding info how to migrate it to the newest API. I am using now RestHighLevelCLient and ElasticSearchRestTemplate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use spring-data you usually define repositories to query the data.
It also supports naitive queries.

Check this out:
https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-elasticsearch-tutorial

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The project was originally coded by someone else. Switching to repositories would require deeper changes. I'd prefer just migrating this query.

Comment: I think I found something. -> https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/elasticsearch/docs/current/reference/html/#elasticsearch.misc

Comment: @Alex_M You can use NativeSearchQueryBuilder. Check the section 5.2 of the tutorial above.

Comment: Actually the link I provided does exactly that in the first two code samples.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I ended up doing, similar to [the link](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/elasticsearch/docs/current/reference/html/#elasticsearch.misc) to spring doc I provided in another comment.

```
NativeSearchQuery query = new NativeSearchQueryBuilder()
    .withQuery(QueryBuilders.matchAllQuery())
    .withFilter(QueryBuilders.boolQuery().must(QueryBuilders.termQuery("mostRecent", true)))
    .build();

SearchHitsIterator<Produkt> stream = template.searchForStream(query, MyClass.class);
```

Unfortunately using pagination ended up in an error message. Hope this will be fixed in some future release.